# Problemas ao abrir software c++ em outro PC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dll, opencv

Estou desenvolvendo um software em c++ utilizando o Visual Studio 2015, e estou utilizando duas bibliotecas externas o OPENCV e o FlyCapture2.
Desenvolvi o software e ele roda normalmente em meu computador, mas na hora de passar para outro computador ele diz que está faltando dll,

o que eu já tentei:
Configurei o caminhos de include e biblioteca do modo release,gerei o executável, instalei o visual c++ redisbutable, mas mesmo assim, o programa não abre em outro computador.

O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: Você obtém alguma mensagem de erro ao executá-lo em outra máquina?

Comment: Precisa verificar quais DLLs ele esta utilizando e copia-las para as maquinas que você quer que ele rode.

Comment: @Renan Aparece a seguinte mensagem: O aplicativo não pode ser inicializado corretamente(0xc000007b) Clique em OK para fechar

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo então antes aparecia mensagem que estava faltando algumas DLL, mas eu já adicionei ela e o que aparece pra mim agora é o erro que comentei acima

Comment: Esse erro é muito genérico, pode ter zilhões de motivos. Tem um erro de lógica, estrutura, programação, sei lá o que em algum lugar. Mas, como ele roda na sua maquina e chutaria que a versão da DLL que você colocou na outra maquina não é a mesma que esta rodando na sua.

Comment: Você compilou ele como Release? Digo isso porque compilando como Debug ele usa uma versão de debug do runtime que eu acho que não é incluída no visual c++ redist

Comment: Aconteceu isso quando quis passar um joguinho que criei para outros computadores. O que fiz foi ir adicionando os DLLs que o computador pedia mas colocava-os na pasta onde estava o excutável e funcionou .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um programa chamado [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), que pode analisar as dependências de um arquivo executável. Tente abrir o seu programa com ele e depois jogue todos os arquivos DLL que ele indicar na mesma pasta do seu programa(incluindo o Visual C++ runtime).

Nunca usei essas bibliotecas, mas acredito que as DLL devam ficar na pasta que você compilou elas.

Comment: Obrigado, usando esse Dependency Walker apareceu as dlls que faltavam no outro computador, e ao adicionar elas na pasta do arquivo conseguir rodar o programa.